# Proof that a linear transformation is injective iff its null space is trivial

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Suppose that $T : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is a linear transformation. Prove that $T$ is injective if and only
>   if $N(T) = \{0\}$.

So I know that if something is injective it has a one to one mapping and if $T(X)=T(X')$ then $X=X'$.

I thought initially that since $N(T)=\{x \in \Bbb R \mid T(x)=0\}$ I could multiply both sides by $T^{-1}$ but since it goes from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$ it's not a square matrix so it can't have an inverse so I'm stuck. Does anyone have sang ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since $T^{-1}$ doesn't necessarily exist, that's not going to be the correct approach.  We're going to have to use only the properties we know -- such as the definitions of injectivity and nullspace.

**"Only if":**

Let $T: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ be an injective linear transformation.  Then $T(x) = T(y) \implies x=y$.  Let $a\in N(T)$.   Then $$T(a) = 0 = T(0) \implies a = 0$$  Thus $N(T) = \{0\}$.

**"If:"**

Let $T: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ be a linear transformation such that $N(T) = \{0\}$.  Let $a,b\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $T(a) = T(b)$.  Then $$T(a) - T(b) = 0 \implies T(a-b) = 0 \stackrel{(*)}\implies a-b = 0 \implies a = b$$

where $(*)$ is due to the fact that the only vector which maps to $0$ under $T$ is $0$.  Thus $T$ is injective.$\ \ \ \square$